# Google Analytics and Instagram

Tags: google-analytics, instagram

Why do I have website traffic coming from Instagram in my analytics when I don't have an Instagram account?

[image of analytics report](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qnb0aorkurfwqsp/Analytics.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have social accounts to get traffic from those sources.

This could be anything from someone linking to your site from their own Instagram account to a bot hiding behind an Instagram referrer. Use other reports and dimensions to find some context to that info (such as `Hostname`, `Landing Page`, `Bounce Rate`) and/or even a segment to determine what else the user did.

It may not illuminate much since there was only 1 acquisition from Instagram (especially if they bounced).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. That makes sense. I've done some digging in other reports but can't find anymore info. I will check again though.